# How can i convert this byte properly?

Tags: python, arrays, byte, python-3.5

I have a byte array `b'string\x01'` that i need to format to `string1`. I need to do this for any "string", followed by a byte e.g, `b'string\t'` to `string9`. Why is my way not correctly working?

I have tried to get the `x = b'string\x01'`, i am trying to turn into `"string1"`. 
So i need to remove the  `'\x01'`, `s = str(x).split("g",1)` and then `byte_part = s[1].rstrip('\'')` so i get `"\x01"` on its own, but the next problem is:

I am trying to convert this string to a byte, so i can use `int.from_bytes(byte_part,'little')` and get the correct integer result. e.g. `\x01 = 1`.

What is happening is i am converting the string to a bytearray `bytearray(string, 'utf-8')` which then gives me `bytearray(b'\\x01')` then using `int.from_bytes()` gives me the result for `b'\\x01'` is `825260124` instead of `b'\x01'` being `1` i am after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are looking for is ord().

```
ord('\x01') # the result is 1
```

Also, following would convert your string and return the last number.

```
ord(a.decode().split('string')[1])
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!!